# <tbody> cannot appear as a child of <div> and <div> cannot appear as a child of <table>

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, radix-ui, html-tbody

Please take a look at the schematic structure of my table. I removed all unnecessary stuff for ease of reading. As you can see, there is a header and there is a body. Only the body is wrapped in ScrollArea (https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/scroll-area), since I want the user to be able to scroll only the body and not the entire table

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <ScrollArea.Root>
  <ScrollArea.Viewport>
   {data.map((person) => (
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>{person.name}</td>
       <td>{person.surname}</td>
       <td>{person.city}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  ))}
  </ScrollArea.Viewport>
  <ScrollArea.Scrollbar/>
 </ScrollArea.Root>
</table>
```

And so, when I go to the page with this table, I receive two warnings in the console:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): div cant appear as a child of table.
>
> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): tbody cannot appear as a child of
> div.

If I remove ScrollArea from the table, then the warnings disappear. But ScrollArea is very important to me for moving through long tables.

Tell me how can I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: A guess into the wild: "ScrollArea" wraps it content into a div element. You need to change that (if possible) to "tbody". Note: i never worked with radix, but i know something familiar from vue. Because "ScrollArea" is/creates a div element under the hood, you need to change that.

Comment: @Marc Yes, I understand that. But the fact of the matter is that I can’t find the divs in the ScrollArea

Comment: Are you looking at the rendered HTML when looking for the divs?

Comment: @Sean Sorry, I didn't understand your question completely. I was looking for divs in the code ScrollArea

Comment: It would help to share the rendered markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the user to be able to scroll only the body and not the entire table

It can be done with simple CSS as well using [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning):

```css
.wrap {
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  
  background-color: pink;
  height: 50px;
}
td {
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<p>a table with sticky header</p>
<div class=wrap>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <!-- {data.map((person) => ( -->
    <tr><td>name1</td><td>surname1</td><td>city1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name2</td><td>surname2</td><td>city2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name3</td><td>surname3</td><td>city3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name4</td><td>surname4</td><td>city4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name5</td><td>surname5</td><td>city5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name6</td><td>surname6</td><td>city6</td></tr>
   <!-- ))} -->
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to break down your table into smaller components and then wrap those smaller components with `<ScrollArea>` tags when applicable.

What you would want to do is separate your code into two different files:

(table.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import * as ScrollArea from '@radix-ui/react-scroll-area';
import './styles.css';

import scrollArea_tbody from '../components/scrollArea_tbody';

const table = () => (
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <scrollArea_tbody />
</table>
);

export default table;
```

(scrollArea_tbody.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import * as ScrollArea from '@radix-ui/react-scroll-area';
import './styles.css';

const scrollArea_tbody = () => (
 <ScrollArea.Root>
  <ScrollArea.Viewport>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </ScrollArea.Viewport>
  <ScrollArea.Scrollbar/>
 </ScrollArea.Root>
);

export default ScrollAreaDemo;
```

To build a component, I would follow along with the React documentation; specifically starting here would be a good call: https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. Yes, your approach is interesting, but I don’t quite understand how to do it in code. I would be grateful if you could provide an example in code form

Comment: I added a link to what should be the easiest way to learn how to implement components in React. If you still feel a bit lost, a phenomenal course I'd recommend is here: https://codewithmosh.com/p/the-ultimate-react-native-course

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand how this applies to my problem. As you can see, I'm only wrapping the body, not the entire table. Could you give an example with my code?

Comment: I edited the answer to better represent what you would need to do by breaking down your code into two separate components. Let me know if you have any confusion still.

Answer (score -1):

By studying how *table* and *ScrollArea* work, I managed to find a solution on my own. The essence of the solution turned out to be to place *thead* and *tbody* in different *tables*

```
<>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>City</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>

 <ScrollArea.Root>
  <ScrollArea.Viewport>
   <table>
   {data.map((person) => (
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>{person.name}</td>
       <td>{person.surname}</td>
       <td>{person.city}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  ))}
   </table>
  </ScrollArea.Viewport>
  <ScrollArea.Scrollbar/>
 </ScrollArea.Root>
</>
```

Comment: This is [invalid markup](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#:~:text=The%20following%20summarizes%20which%20tags,may%20always%20be%20safely%20omitted.) and an accessibility problem. It'll also leave your columns out of alignment unless you explicitly size them, and even that's unreliable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).